# How to declare a numeric array of size around a 10 digit number or greater?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a numeric(or integer, whatever you wanna call it since its out of the integer and long range) array..say of the size. Here's my code. When i execute it, i get the 'Out Of Memory Heap Size' exception
I've even tried increasing the size of the dump file or whatever in the HVM configuration. Doesn't Work

CODE snippet(Dont necessarily need to understand. Just skip to the end:

```
int dsum=0;
int c1=-1;
int abno[]=new int[28124];

for(int i=2;i<28124;i++)
{
    int f=(i/2);
    for(int j=1;j<=f;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            dsum+=j;
        }
    }
    if(dsum>i)
    {
        c1++;// AROUND 29000 IN THE END
        abno[c1]=i;
    }
}
int abnos[]=new int[(c1*(c1+1))/2];//CANT STORE THIS BIG A VALUE
```

Comment: Check that the calculation returns the value you think it does. If so, you need to make the heap even bigger.

Comment: What is the **full stack trace** of the exception? Please **edit it into the question**.

Comment: What is the value of `(c1*(c1+1))/2`?

Comment: @BholaGabbar are you, by any chance, using a 32-bit VM?

Comment: 395353140 the value. @Ordous Bluej supports only 32 bit. Though im running a 64 bit ystem its installed in programfile x86

Answer (score 2):

You can increase heap size in java

```
-Xmx<size> ,maximum heap size
-Xms<size> ,minimium heap size
```

e.g. java -Xms 256m -Xmx 6g yourProgramName. If you are using some IDE(for e.g. intellij) then you can pass these options via VM Options

Comment: I'm using Bluej. As ive mentioned i already tried adding bluej.vm.args=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m to the config file. Doesn't seem to work. Ive even changed 1024 to 2048 and 4062

Comment: @BholaGabbar could you provide me the value of (c1*(c1+1))/2 .

Comment: @BholaGabbar i tried on my machine and these settings worked -Xms256m -Xmx3g

Comment: Where do i enter it? In the configuration file? In the code? Which part? Whats the exact format? Sorry im not new to java but to this i am

Comment: I haven't used BlueJ but try to run your program from command line like java -Xms256m -Xmx3g MyClass ,For BlueJ sepcific see http://www.bluej.org/faq.html.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting just shy of 1.6GB worth of heap space. A 32-bit JVM can address only 1.2-1.6 GB worth of heap space, depending on the OS, environment and exact implementation. No setting can help you here.

Your options are:

- Get a real IDE and configure it to use a 64-bit VM.
- BlueJ is typically used for learning purposes. As such, the tasks are nowhere near something that may require even 100MB of memory, not to mention a gig. Improve the solution to whatever you're doing to use less space.
- Write the code in BlueJ, but launch using command line with a proper 64-bit VM.
- Fix your BlueJ to support 64-bit VMs

Comment: I get what you're saying. I'm pretty sure i cant 'FIX' blueJ for a 64 bit. I'll try it in eclipse. Also, how do i run a java program from command prompt? I'e been in the habit of compiling and using the System.out.print statement in the IDE itself.

Comment: Google "Java run from command line" :) You will need to use `javac` (comes with JDK) to compile your sources into `.class` and possibly package into `.jar` file, then use the `java` program (comes with JDK and JRE) to actually run it. Or, if BlueJ supports packaging - it may be able to make a runnable `.jar` that you just double click (provided your Java is setup properly)